# To Change Default Direction in Descending Order of Pageable Class in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sorting, pagination

How can I change the default direction of the pageable class from ASC to DSEC? Below is the controller I tried with different annotations but it is not working, please share your ideas and suggestion to make it workable.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/lists/{productId}",  produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity getProductList(
                                  @PathVariable(value = "productId", required = true) String productId, 
                                  @Parameter(description="Represents query string parameters which Specify page size, page number and sort order")
                                  @PageableDefault(size=15, page=0, direction = Direction.DESC)
                                  @SortDefault(sort = "lastModifiedDate", direction = Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable)
{
    logger.info("Fetching products for" + productId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.getProductList(productId, pageable));
}
```